# How to increase call volume on Nexus 4?

Tags: volume-control, nexus-4

I just bought a Nexus 4, and this is like my first Android phone. Can someone please help me to increase the call volume? It is really low on my phone. I tried to increase it but the maximum is too low for me.

Answer (score 1):

Call volume can be adjusted by using the volume rocker buttons only during a call. If not in a call, it adjusts ringer volume and if a media is played, it adjusts media volume.

So, if you had mistakenly increased media or ringer volume then you might not have any effect on call volume.

Try making some calls and when it's dialing, press volume up to raise volume level.

I am just saying all this because you said you are new (though this is a common feature for other phones as well) to Android. If you had already done this and still you can't hear properly, I am afraid there are no further solutions to improve the volume. However, there are work around like using hands-free or headphones.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an app like [Volume Control +](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cb.volumePlus) to adjust different types of volumes: Media, Ring, Notifications, In-call, alarm, system.

Answer (score 0):

You can tune volume level for lots of things in your device with [ES Task Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.taskmanager). Go to `Power Optimizer` > `Other` (in the bottom right corner) > `Volume`. Here you can tune the volume level for incoming calls, notifications, medias (music and video), alarm, **volume during a call** and system sounds.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the in call volume. I restarted my phone in safe mode, and it fixed the issue.

To restart the phone is safe mode, hold the power button to turn off phone. Hold the Power Off option for a few seconds and reboot to safe mode. The problem should be fixed once you delete any apps that crash in safe mode. Restart the phone and the volume should be much louder.